# NeedAName? This'll do

Tags: riddle, word

A word used in anticipation,

I'm in a simple machine,
in the witty,
and in boisterous celebration.

I'm in things separated,
in the intense,
and in this clue's valuation.

**What am I?**

---

<sub>As always, the accepted answer will explain how each and every line fits the riddle. Despite brevity and ambiguity, I don't expect too many complaints of this riddle's broadness; it'll probably be solved in under 25 views.</sub>

Comment: My, my, how flattering! I feel obligated to solve it; but I haven't a clue yet (more accurately, I have an idea, but can't make it fit all the lines yet)

Comment: Does the word occur as is in each clue, or could the letters be present but rearranged (say, backwards)?

Comment: As you've now found, the word appears all together in order in each clue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> EVE!

Not sure about all of these...

A word used in anticipation,

> On Chrismas Eve you anticipate Christmas Day

I'm in a simple machine,

> LEVER

in the witty,

> CLEVER

and in boisterous celebration.

> REVEL (thanks, dennisdeems and NeedAName)

I'm in things separated,

> SEVERED

in the intense,

> SEVERE

and in this clue's valuation.

> It's the SEVENTH clue.

And of course...

> EVE is a name!

Comment: Hivemind! I've been trying to make this one fit since yesterday and randomly decided to post what I had

Comment: You're both very close! Try something a little less ambitious. I'll post these comments on both of your posts as quickly as possible. Happy racing!

Comment: @Roland: What about now?

Comment: Stop reading my  mind!

Comment: I've got something else in mind for boisterous celebration, but FEVER fits well enough. I'll accept when you get the final clue correct, for which you currently have EVERY.

Comment: @NeedAName: Welp, I guess we're somehow psychically bonded. Does this conflict with SE's rules on sockpuppet accounts?

Comment: @Roland: Got it!

Comment: @Deusovi, nicely done! Nice catch on the last clue, I looked right over that. Also it's bad enough that Roland and I seem to be sockpuppets already, now you too!

Comment: We're triplets, perhaps! I'll probably give the check to Deusovi, for having SEVENTH and an only slightly incorrect FEVER (similar to the intended REVEL) before NeedAName posted the entirely correct answer. Or you guys can perform some cyber rock-paper-scissors; as it stands, I like NeedAName's answer most.

Comment: Give it to Deusovi on this one. I wasn't that close to the last line when they figured it out.

Comment: @Roland: I'm fine if NAN gets it - after all, this puzzle was semi-dedicated to him! It's entirely your decision.

Answer (score 5):

My new guess (beaten to it by Deusovi) is :

> EVE

A word used in anticipation,

> EVE relates to the time (typically night) before an event, eg Christmas Eve or the eve of battle

I'm in a simple machine,

> L**EVE**R is a simple machine

in the witty,

> CL**EVE**R is synonymous with witty

and in boisterous celebration.

> R**EVE**LRY is defined as a wild celebration

I'm in things separated,

> S**EVE**R means to divide or separate e.g. a severed head

in the intense,

> Two possible candidates here are S**EVE**RE or F**EVE**RISH though I like the first more for this line

and in this clue's valuation.

> As Deusovi noted, this is the S**EVE**NTH line in the poem

NeedAName? This'll do

> EVE makes for a fine name, though I don't think I'd wear it well, what with having a Y chromosome and all.

Comment: Heh, we answered at the exact same time.

Comment: You're both very close! Try something a little less ambitious. I'll post these comments on both of your posts as quickly as possible. Happy racing!

Comment: All of the clues have not yet been solved. If you fit EVE correctly (and fast!) in each you'll get the check.

Answer (score 2):

My first guess is

> INTUITION

A word used in anticipation,

> hope

I'm in a simple machine,

> mach**IN**e

in the witty,

> wi**T**ty

and in boisterous celebration.

> boistero**U**s celebrat**I**on

I'm in things separated,

> **T**hings

in the intense,

> **I**ntense

and in this clue's valuation.

> valuati**ON**

Comment: You missed an 'I'

Comment: @CodeNewbie ty.

Comment: The answer is a word present in each of the clues.

Comment: @Roland Thank you for the clarification. Too late to sign in. maybe next time.

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> The word/letter **I**?

A word used in anticipation,

> **I** is a word, i as a letter is present in ant**i**cipation

I'm in a simple machine,
in the witty,
and in boisterous celebration.
I'm in things separated,
in the intense,
and in this clue's valuation.

> s**I**mple mach**I**ne, w**I**tty, bo**I**sterous celebrat**I**on, th**i**ngs seperated, **i**ntense, valuat**i**on

And the title: NeedAName? this will do

> we can always refer to ourselves as 'I' which is a substitute for our name.

Seems too generic though.

Comment: +1, this works, but my clues aren't just for flavor, and the word in question is more than one letter long.